# Легок на помине

Tags: фразеология

Так говорят о человеке, который появился сразу после того, как он нем зашла речь в разговоре.
В принципе, смысл поговорки ясен, но все-таки интересно было бы в ней разобраться до конца. Почему именно легок и почему НА помине?
Может, лингвисты смогут объяснить? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Процитирую найденное:

"Есть две версии происхождения оборота.

1. От поговорки «легок волк на помине», связанной с древними суевериями, запрещавшими произносить имя зверя вслух: стоит произнести слово «волк» вслух, как волк тотчас же появится. Поэтому в поговорке этого слова нет, оно только подразумевается.
2. Выражение связано с народным обычаем, ритуальным действием. При захоронении поминали не только умерших (за упокой), но и уехавших (за здравие). Если после такого помина человек вскоре возвращался, говорили легок на помине. "

http://iknowit.ru/words/word120113.html

От себя могу добавить, что в английском таким же случаям "появления при упоминании" соответствует присказка: 'speak of the devil' (примерный смысл близок к "волчьей" версии: "помяни только дьявола...").
Почему лёгок? Видимо, таким упоминанием "легко" волка привести. На помине (синоним поминовения из второй версии) - возможно, форма связана не только с тем, что был "помянут НА поминовении", а и с тем, что "НА этих словах, (в помин произнесённых) с лёгкостью появился". Вероятно, здесь обе версии смутным образом соединяются.